# How Oracle processes the given SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, execution

Could you please explain how the query will be executed? Step by Step explanation please...

```
select
  max(salary),
  country_id
from (
  select
    salary,
    department_id,
    location_id,
    country_id
  from
    HR.EMPLOYEES
  natural join
    HR.DEPARTMENTS
  natural join
    HR.LOCATIONS
)
group by country_id;
```

Comment: The optimizer will determine the step by step instructions for execution based on what it knows about the specifics of your machine and data.

Comment: Generate the explain plan and analyze yourself.

Comment: I don't think it will be executed. I think it will raise an `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` error.

Comment: @DavidFaber Why? Subquery is just one level deep. It executes fine. I used the same query in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to understand the execution steps of the SQL is to generate the **explain plan** and analyze from innermost `ID` to the outermost.

```
SQL> explain plan for
  2  select
  3    max(salary),
  4    country_id
  5  from (
  6    select
  7      salary,
  8      department_id,
  9      location_id,
 10      country_id
 11    from
 12      HR.EMPLOYEES
 13    natural join
 14      HR.DEPARTMENTS
 15    natural join
 16      HR.LOCATIONS
 17  )
 18  group by country_id;

Explained.

SQL>
```

Let's display the explain plan in a readable format:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1571404374

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |             |    11 |   297 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                 |             |    11 |   297 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                    |             |    11 |   297 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    MERGE JOIN                  |             |    11 |   176 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| LOCATIONS   |    23 |   138 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      INDEX FULL SCAN           | LOC_ID_PK   |    23 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     SORT JOIN                  |             |    11 |   110 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL         | DEPARTMENTS |    11 |   110 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL           | EMPLOYEES   |   107 |  1177 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("EMPLOYEES"."DEPARTMENT_ID"="DEPARTMENTS"."DEPARTMENT_ID" AND
              "EMPLOYEES"."MANAGER_ID"="DEPARTMENTS"."MANAGER_ID")
   6 - access("DEPARTMENTS"."LOCATION_ID"="LOCATIONS"."LOCATION_ID")
       filter("DEPARTMENTS"."LOCATION_ID"="LOCATIONS"."LOCATION_ID")
   7 - filter("DEPARTMENTS"."MANAGER_ID" IS NOT NULL)

Note
-----
   - this is an adaptive plan

28 rows selected.

SQL>
```

The **Query Transformer** can determine whether to rewrite the query so that the **optimizer** could generate a better execution plan.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/sqllangu.htm#CNCPT88912):

> **Estimator**
>
> The estimator determines the overall cost of a given execution plan.
>   The estimator generates three different types of measures to achieve
>   this goal:
>
> - Selectivity
>
>   This measure represents a fraction of rows from a row set. The selectivity is tied to a query predicate, such as last_name='Smith',
>     or a combination of predicates.
> - Cardinality
>
>   This measure represents the number of rows in a row set.
> - Cost
>
>   This measure represents units of work or resource used. The query optimizer uses disk I/O, CPU usage, and memory usage as units of work.
>
> If statistics are available, then the estimator uses them to compute
>   the measures. The statistics improve the degree of accuracy of the
>   measures.

I would suggest to read the documentation link I have provided above.